# Does Committing Editor - SharedPreferences Close the Transaction?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I am going to have three SharedPreferences:

```
 
private SharedPreferences cakes, tarts, pies;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
....

cakes = getSharedPreferences("cakes", MODE_PRIVATE);
tarts = getSharedPreferences("tarts", MODE_PRIVATE);
pies = getSharedPreferences("pies", MODE_PRIVATE);
....

editor = cakes.edit();
editor.putLong("date", Shane.getTime());
editor.commit(); // <--- does this let me use editor again, like so:

editor = tarts.edit();
editor.putLong("date", Shane.getTime());
editor.commit();

...and so on
```

Can I just keep calling `editor = *.edit();` as long as I commit the changes to the SharedPreferences?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All you need to do to complete your transaction is call `commit` as you already are.